# Azure AD B2C audit trace - Client ID

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Is there any way to detect which app or at least which user journey caused a particular event in B2C? I am particularly interested in seeing how many users signed up to a particular application.

Comment: Hi Mark: Are you using built-in or custom policies?

Comment: Custom policies. Ah, perhaps tracking user behavior (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-guide-eventlogger-appins  can do this for me.

Comment: Correct. I've added another answer that describes how to track the client application.

Answer (score 2):

If you are creating a custom policy, then you can [send a custom event to Azure Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-guide-eventlogger-appins).

If you are wanting to track which client application was logged in to by the end user, then you must reference [the `client_id` query string parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview#openid-connect) as an input claim in the **AzureApplicationInsightsProvider** technical profile:

```xml
<ClaimType Id="clientId">
  <DisplayName>Client Identifier</DisplayName>
  <DataType>string</DataType>
</ClaimType>
```

```xml
<InputClaims>
  <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="clientId" PartnerClaimType="{property:ClientId}" DefaultValue="{OIDC:ClientId}" />
</InputClaims>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consumer logins are available in the audit logs for B2C. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-audit-logs

Application assignment is not supported in B2C so I don't think those logs would be available. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/methods-for-assigning-users-and-groups

Comment: I was not asking for details based on app assignments (as in regular AAD). I was asking about properties which are included in the signin request, issued by an application, which then resulted in a user signing up. The signin request contains both the journey/policy id and the client id. Is there any way to correlate either value to the events provided in the audit logs, e.g. 'Add user' event?